# I am trying to make a program that tracts the most frequent character in a string presented by a user. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: python

This is what I've come up with so far. it gives me an error saying that "each" is not defined and I don't know what to do to make it work. I am very new to coding so any advice is much appreciated.

```
my_string = input("Enter a sentence: ")

def main(my_string):
    count = {}
    for ch in my_string:
        if ch in count:
            count[each] += 1
        else:
            count[each] = 1
    return count

main(my_string)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `each`? You never defined it in your code.

Comment: ```each``` is indeed not defined. see, that you are referencing it, yet nowhere before you define it in any shape or form. Try ```ch``` instead of ```each``` I suspect that's what you meant.

Comment: Instead of the `if ch in count:...` you could use `count[ch] = count.get(ch,0) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to say `ch` instead of `each` both times.

This error is coming up because you never defined the `each` variable before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change that `each` variable into `ch`

```
my_string = input("Enter a sentence: ")

def main(my_string):
    count = {}
    for ch in my_string:
        if ch in count:
            count[ch] += 1
        else:
            count[ch] = 1
    return count

main(my_string)
```